# AMD CPU SSE3 problem in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, cpu

AMD Phenom II X4 965
In the bios of my system AMD SSE3 is Yes.but ubuntu 16.04 does not support it. I checked it with this command:
`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep flags`
In addition when I run android sdk emulator I get this error
**WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86 emulation: SSSE3**

Answer (score 2):

Your CPU is really don't support [SSS3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSSE3). Please don't confuse with [SSE3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE3), that difference thing :).

AMD CPU that support for SSSE3 listed in this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSSE3#CPUs_with_SSSE3).